# Replace EMUI systemui with stock

Tags: system, system-apps, systemless-root

My phone broke just a bit too early. I am currently waiting for a Fairphone 4, but the delivery time is quite long, so I am stuck with an old Honor 9 Lite which we had lying around.

But EMUI is really annoying, especially the systemui.

Is there a way to replace the systemui with the AOSP version of that? I have root (Magisk), but since I won't be using this phone for too long, I wouldn't want to flash a custom rom.

Comment: No way without flashing a custom ROM or  AOSP//You can tinker with *some* UI features but not make it look like  AOSP // That's true for any heavily modified ROM like yours or Samsung or any other

Comment: try another app drawer like nexus launcher

Comment: @alecxs Thanks, I already have another launcher (KISS launcher, it is amazing!) The biggest problem i have now is that the systemui (it's responsible e.g. for the notification area) is scaled super large. So I can see e.g. only 3 Notifications at once, and the text is so large, that I can't see more than a few words. Scaling it smaller using normal means doesn't change anything.

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks for the answer. I was fearing that...